# SQL Server - What is the easiest way to loop through the values of a table variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example the table variable `@TABEL_VARIABLE` below including the values selected from `ANOTHER_TABLE.myVar2` :

```
DECLARE @Table_Variable (myVar VARCHAR(MAX)) 

INSERT INTO @Table_Variable (myVar)
    SELECT myVar2 
    FROM ANOTHER_TABLE
```

What is the easiest way to loop through the values in `@Table_Variable.myVar` and put them inside another table or table variable?

Comment: What's a "variabel"?

Comment: `INSERT INTO @other_table_variable (myVar) SELECT myVar FROM @Table_Variable`?

Comment: A table starting with @ ? Dynamic? Tell me if I'm wrong. @roryap

Comment: @plalx looping through the values of `@Table_Variable` and select them one by one!

Comment: @Tomb_Raider_Legend Why do you want to do that? The only way is with a cursor and cursors are wrongly used 99% of the time. Is that an academic exercise? I almost never had to use cursors in 8 years of programming.

Comment: Are you trying to do this using ONLY SQL?  If you have some sort of application layer that you're using (doesn't really matter for the most part what it is), you're usually better off returning the results from the SQL, and cycling through them at the application level.

Comment: @user2366842 Yes I do, however as plalx just mentioned about cursor, it would be great if anyone could give an example of how to loop through the values with cursor or any another methods if there are any. Otherwise it can be done by searching on the internet.

Comment: Generally speaking, @plalx was exactly right.  Whenever you're using a cursor, you're doing something that really shouldn't be done directly within SQL.  I'm sure there's plenty of examples out there on cursor usage, but you should note that it's usually frowned upon (sorta similar to using goto in most modern programming languages).  EDIT: Here's an example if you're absolutely certain you NEED to go down that route:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: To me, it almost sounds like OP is asking for a simple UPDATE with a join. Loop through one table updating rows with data from another.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give a practical example I've used repeatedly to defeat the limitation against nested INSERT EXECs. Basically, this approach just increments a counter to loop over a table variable, much like in a standard For I = 0 loop in C# or VB.Net. In this particular example, I use it to select a different schema, table and column on each pass and retrieve an aggregate, which is then used to UPDATE values in another table. You could use the same approach to perform other operations in the loop besides doing a RBAR update to defeat INSERT EXEC; this is the most practical use I've found for it to date though. I'm sure there are ways the code can be improved (I also have more sophisticated versions to handle multiple conditions, etc.) but the design pattern remains the same. It probably won't perform well on large queries where set-based solutions are almost always preferable, but there are niche uses for this approach. I hope this helps; if you need any clarifications etc. please let me know. :)

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max),
@CurrentTableVarID bigint = 0,
@MaxTableVarID bigint = 0,
@CounterCheck bigint = 0,
@ParameterDefinition nvarchar(500),
@MaxID bigint,
@MaxIDOut bigint

SET @SQLString = ''

SELECT @MaxTableVarID = Max(ID) FROM @ResultTable GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID ASC
SELECT @CurrentTableVarID =Max(ID) FROM @ResultTable GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID  DESC

WHILE @CurrentTableVarID <= @MaxTableVarID
BEGIN   

        SELECT @SchemaName = SchemaNAme, @TableName = TableName, 
        @ColumnName = ColumnName
        FROM @MyTableVar
        WHERE ID = @CurrentTableVarID

        SET @ParameterDefinition = '@MaxIDOut bigint OUTPUT';
        SET @SQLString = 'SELECT @MaxIDOut = Max(' + @ColumnName + ') FROM [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + '] GROUP BY ' + @ColumnName + ' ORDER BY ' + @ColumnName + ' ASC'

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParameterDefinition, @MaxIDOut = @MaxID  OUTPUT

        UPDATE @ResultTable
        SET MaxID = @MaxID
        WHERE ID = @CurrentTableVarID


    SET     @CounterCheck = @CounterCheck  + 1
    SET @CurrentTableVarID = @CurrentTableVarID + 1 -- increment the loop
END
```